# Getting an unexpected output

Tags: python, class, output

This is my first question ever! I'm just learning how to code in Python, so don't be to hard on me.

I wrote the following class in Python and when I call the method describe_restaurant (located in the parent class), I get this 'none' output right after the description.

I can't figure out why this is happening, and I can't get rid of this 'none' output.

Here is an image of my code:

[image: Image here, I marked the output with an arrow.]

Thank you for the help on such a lousy question!

Comment: Add any code / errors as text formatted as code not images. Check [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: don't call `print()` with `describe_restaurant()` as `describe_restaurant()` by default returns None since nothing is returned so you do `print(None)` and `None` gets printed. just do `my_iceCreamStand.describe_restaurant()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on line 38 you call:

`print(my_iceCreamStand.describeRestaurant())`

the function `describeRestaurant()` doesn't have a return so returns `None` by deafault. Hence why you are seeing `None` printed out.

If you dont want to see the `None`. Simply call the function without the print:
`my_iceCreamStand.describeRestaurant()`